# State management in GWT?

Tags: gwt, state

How does one manage state in a GWT application? I am much more experienced in JSF development and every bean is scoped to either request, session, application, conversation, page etc etc. How does that work in GWT? Any reading tips on state management in GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you're presenting your site as a browser-based application or a series of pages.  In the application style, the user rarely navigates away from the app's URL, so the GWT module is long-lived and the server is relatively stateless.  In the sequence-of-pages style, the GWT module would be restarted each time the user browses to a new URL, so the server has to maintain state to send back to the client on each page load.

Writing state-management for the application style uses the same patterns as any kind of desktop or server app.  You usually have some service object that brokers data exchange with the server (GWT-RPC or RequestFactory) and the broker is made available to the various objects in your module that require state.  Objects store their state in fields and have a lifetime corresponding to their usefulness (e.g. Widgets vs. caches vs. ephemeralia).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general I view it this way: Usually, your GWT app is one website with a lot of javascript code. In that code, all fields (member variables) of all the client java classes are your state. Additionally, you can embed IDs or variable values in the DOM of the dynamic website (e.g. an attribute "xyz" as part of an tag). They also contribute to your state. Therefore, all the "data" plus the DOM is the state.

On a coarser level, you can encode state's in the URL after a "#" sign. They are called "Places" or "History", depending on which implementation you choose. (GWT's History, mvp4g, ...)

If you need some user management, you can then request a token from the server after successful authentication, store it locally in the client (change it's state), and then include it for each server request.